# creating indices with multiple fields

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2012, database-indexes

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

I have a table shown below,

```
create table myTable
(
    Id int identity(1, 1) constraint PK_myTable primary key(Id),
    DateEntry date,
    FundCode nvarchar(10),
    Sedol nvarchar(7),
    Name nvarchar(150),
    Nominal int,
    PriceDate date,
    Price float,
    PriceCcy nvarchar(3),
    PriceSource nvarchar(30)
 )
```

So most of the select queries will be on the dateEntry field & the FundCode field.

So I decided to create the two indices below. I was wondering though if we can make the assumption that every select query will have a DateEntry as part of the where clause would the first index be needed? Because if the FundCode wasn't supplied it could still use the second index or is that incorrect?

```
create index IX_tblEQ_Holdings_Date on tblFI_Holdings(DateEntry)
create index IX_tblEQ_Holdings_DateFund on tblFI_Holdings(DateEntry, FundCode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If index has more than 1 field, queries can use only use part of them, but only from the left side, so for example if index has fields A, B and C, query can use A, or A and B or A, B and C, but not A and C.

In your case you're probably ok with just the second index. The first one would of course be slightly smaller, but it also causes overhead in updates / inserts, so usually it's not a good idea to create indexes like that.